# Number of ways to $N/2$ white blocks and $N/2$ black blocks given $N$ spaces

Tags: combinatorics

> Say you have $N$ spaces with $N$ being even, and you have $N/2$ white blocks and $N/2$ black blocks to fill in the $N$ spaces. The white blocks are indistinguishable, and likewise for the black blocks. How many ways can you combine the white and black blocks?

For low $N$ its easy to draw up all the combinations, but I haven't been able to find a general rule yet. For $N = 2$ I obtain 2 combinations, and $N = 4$ I obtain 4, but it seems like theres way more than $N$ combinations in general for $N$ higher than $4$.

Comment: How do the arrangements differ if the order of the blocks doesn't matter? Perhaps you mean that the order of the white blocks among themselves doesn't matter, and likewise for the black blocks, but the order in which white and black blocks are combined does matter? (This is also sometimes expressed by saying that all white blocks are "indistinguishable", and likewise for the black blocks.) If this is what you mean, then $4$ is not the correct count for $N=4$ -- you might want to explicate which $4$ arrangements you found.

Comment: Quite... it sounds like you are simply trying to count the [central binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)

Comment: @joriki Yes I meant that the white blocks are indistinguishable, and likewise for the black ones. For $N = 4$ I obtained BBWW WWBB BWBW WBWB.

Comment: For $N = 4$, you should have BBWW, BWBW, BWWB, WBBW, WBWB, WWBB.

Comment: @JMoravitz In that case $ N = 4$ gives me the answer 70, when it should be 6. Unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: @Pame yes, you misunderstood something.  You can phrase it as $N/2$ black blocks and $N/2$ white blocks and $N$ blocks total, or you can phrase it as $K$ black blocks, $K$ white blocks and $2K$ blocks total.  However you wish to phrase it, if you have some total combined number of blocks, that is what appears in the top of the binomial coefficient.  The number of white blocks is what appears in the bottom of the binomial coefficient.  Whether you what to call that $\binom{N}{N/2}$ or whether you want to call that $\binom{2K}{K}$ or what have you

Comment: With four blocks total, two of which white, that gives $\binom{4}{2} = 6$.  With eight blocks total, four of which white, that gives $\binom{8}{4} = 70$.  This is a rudimentary application of [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).